# Google Maps coloured overlay/polygon that only applies to water

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to plot some coastal areas that are are easily defined in English (eg "water in the bay north of latitude X"), but are highly complex polygons because of the shoreline.

Do I have to plot the the entire (relevant) section of shoreline, or is there a way to draw a rectangle that only colours the water (and has no effect on land)?

Answer (score 0):

The maps drawing tools have no knowledge of the terrain type. The tiles that show up are just background images that Google has generated from various data sources: there isn't data attached to them by the time you use the API that says "this pixel is land" or "this pixel is water". Even so, the drawing tools of Google Maps are fairly "dumb": they just allow you to plot geometric primitives on a canvas which has a coordinate system that matches latitude/longitude.

Sadly, this means that your geometry needs to be drawn to match the shoreline if you don't want it to overlap. There are resources for this, such as [the NOAA shoreline data](http://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/ocsshore.html), but it's a non-trivial amount of work to consume the data and serve it up in the map.